# What is the difference between a model defined function and a function in a partial class in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I am reading the following book: [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652028X) and I am having a hard time distinguishing the difference between a "Model Defined Function" defined in the CSDL and a function I would create in a Partial class of my own (i.e. Partial class of my 'Customer' entity) that I create.

So the example in the book is a Function that concatenates and returns someone's full name as below:

```
<DefiningExpression>
   Trim(c.LastName) + ", " + Trim(c.FirstName)
</DefiningExpression>
```

I could create a Property or Function in my Partial Customer class that could do the same thing? What is the advantage or main draw to creating these model defined functions in the CSDL for an Entity Framework Data Model as opposed to me doing it in my Partial classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that model defined function is part of your model and you can use it in ESQL or Linq-to-entities queries because EF knows how to translate it to SQL. When you create common .NET function in partial class you cannot use it in Linq-to-entities or ESQL queries because EF doesn't know how to translate them.